# my if elif and 'and' returning none type

Tags: python-3.x

```
def taxcalc(gsalary2):
   tax=0
   if(gsalary2 <= 10164):
      tax = 0
    elif gsalary2 > 10164 and gsalary2 <= 19740 :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = (15 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 10164))
      tax = tax1 + tax2
    elif gsalary2 > 19740 and gsalary2 <= 29316 :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = 15 / 100 * 9576
      tax3 = (20 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 19740))
      tax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3
    elif (gsalary2 > 29316 and gsalary2 <= 38892) :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = 15 / 100 * 9576
      tax3 = 20 / 100 * 9576
      tax4 = 25 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 29316)
      tax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4
    elif gsalary2 > 38892 :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = 15 / 100 * 9576
      tax3 = 20 / 100 * 9576
      tax4 = 25 / 100 * 9576
      tax5 = 30 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 38892)
      tax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4 + tax5
    return tax
```

The above function fails totally
only this section seems to work

```
elif gsalary2 > 38892 :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = 15 / 100 * 9576
      tax3 = 20 / 100 * 9576
      tax4 = 25 / 100 * 9576
      tax5 = 30 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 38892)
      tax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4 + tax5
      return tax
```

Comment: All `elif`s are working for me, I don't see where is the problem.

Comment: After fixing up indentation everything works fine.

Comment: @grael if elif is like below it only works for the last block. the way i pasted it above it is actually okey and will work perfectly                                                                                                    elif gsalary2 > 38892 :
      tax1 = 10 / 100 * 10164
      tax2 = 15 / 100 * 9576
      tax3 = 20 / 100 * 9576
      tax4 = 25 / 100 * 9576
      tax5 = 30 / 100 * (gsalary2 - 38892)
      tax = tax1 + tax2 + tax3 + tax4 + tax5
      return tax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `return tax` line is at the same indentation level as your `if ...`. The way you have it now, it looks like it will only return a value if your last `elif` is true. You are getting `None` (instead of `0`) because your function is not returning anything and therefore returns the default `None` instead. In other words, you need to make sure you always return `tax`.

```
def taxcalc(gsalary2):
    tax = 0
    if(gsalary2 <= 10164):
    ...
    return tax
```

Comment: Thanks guys i figured it out after running the code in another step by step website. Adding return tax after each block does the magic.

Comment: @ANjagi in that case your result will be the same (and much cleaner) if you return tax once *after* the whole thing like I suggested, instead of one in each block. It will save you one line of code per block. If your code enters one block, if will never enter another.